# How to use console in php?

Tags: php, encryption, console, console-application, html

I need to write a php code that asks the user to enter password into a console and encrypt this password and send the encrypted password to a web page. 
I don't know how to provide a console window to the user using php code and how to take this data to be processed using the php code and send encrypted version to the web page.

Comment: RTFM? http://php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php

Answer (score 0):

You can create your script as any shell script.

Remember to set the proper permissions and ad the corresponding shebang like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
    var_dump($argv);
?>
```